# Why does the numeric error in my implementation of Runge-Kutta not decrease like N^a?

Tags: matlab, runge-kutta

I'm trying to determine how many steps it takes for the [Runge-Kutta Method](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Runge-KuttaMethod.html) ("RK4") to be within 0.01% of the exact solution of an ordinary differential equation. I'm comparing this to the [Euler method](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerForwardMethod.html).  Both should result in a straight line on a loglog plot.  My Euler solution seems to be correct but I am getting a curved solution for RK.  They are based on the same code so I am completely confused about the problem.

EDIT: Sorry for removing the wikipedia links.  It wouldn't let me keep more than one link since I'm a new user.  However, both methods are detailed on Wikipedia similarly to my implementation.

Should someone wish to tackle my problem, the code is below and graphs are in [this Word file on dropbox.com](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5962491/td4.4.doc). Yes this is a homework problem; I'm posting this because I'd like to understand what is wrong in my thought process.

```
f = @(x,y) x+y; %this is the eqn (the part after the @(t,y)
```

This is my RK4 code:

```
k1=@(x,y) h*f(x,y);
k2=@(x,y) h*f(x+1/2*h,y+1/2*k1(x,y));
k3=@(x,y) h*f(x+1/2*h,y+1/2*k2(x,y));
k4=@(x,y) h*f(x+h,y+k3(x,y));

clear y x exact i
x(1)=0;
y(1)=2;
xn=1;
x0=0;

exact=3*exp(xn)-xn-1; %exact solution at x=1
%# Evaluate RK4 with 1 step for x=0...1
N=1; %# number of steps
h=(xn-x0)/N; %# step size
i=1;
y(i+1)=y(i)+1/6*k1(x(i),y(i))+1/3*k2(x(i),y(i))+1/3*k3(x(i),y(i))+1/6*k4(x(i),y(i));
RK4(N)=y(i+1);  %# store result of RK4 in vector RK4(# of steps)
E_RK4(N)=-(RK4(N)-exact)/exact*100;%keep track of %error for each N
Nsteps_RK4(N)=N;


%# repeat for increasing N until error is less than 0.01%
while -(RK4(N)-exact)/exact > 0.0001
    i=1;
    N=N+1;
    h=(xn-x0)/N;
    for i=1:N
        y(i+1)=y(i)+1/6*k1(x(i),y(i))+1/3*k2(x(i),y(i))+1/3*k3(x(i),y(i))+1/6*k4(x(i),y(i));
        x(i+1)=x(i)+h;
    end
    RK4(N)=y(i+1);
    Nsteps_RK4(N)=N;
    E_RK4(N)=-(RK4(N)-exact)/exact*100; %# keep track of %error for each N
end

Nsteps_RK4(end);
```

This is my Euler code:

```
%# Evaluate Euler with 1 step for x=0...1
clear y x i
x(1)=0;
y(1)=2;
N=1; %# number of steps
h=(xn-x0)/N; %# step size
i=1;
y(i+1)= y(i)+h*f(x(i),y(i));
Euler(N)=y(i+1); %# store result of Euler in vector Euler(# of steps)
E_Euler(N)=-(Euler(N)-exact)/exact*100;%# keep track of %error for each N
Nsteps_Euler(N)=N;
%# repeat for increasing N until error is less than 0.01%
while -(Euler(N)-exact)/exact > 0.0001
    i=1;
    N=N+1;
    h=(xn-x0)/N;
    for i=1:N
        y(i+1)= y(i)+h*f(x(i),y(i));   
        x(i+1)=x(i)+h;
    end
    Euler(N)=y(i+1);
    Nsteps_Euler(N)=N;
    E_Euler(N)=-(Euler(N)-exact)/exact*100; %# keep track of %error for each N
end
```

Comment: How is the function `f` defined?

Comment: Hi, as stardt said you should tell us which `f`you are supposed to use. Also, can you make sure the Wikipedia article links I added correctly reflect the version of RK4 you are using?

Comment: There are many problems with the code you posted. `h` is used in the anonymous functions before it is defined. You should use `abs()` in the `while` conditions because I don't see how you can guarantee that the estimate will always be less than the exact solution. You access the wrong element of the `y` vector after computing the values in the `for` loop. The line after `end` should be `RK4(N) = y(N+1)`. The same mistakes are in the euler code.

Comment: Also, changing `h` in the `while` loop does not affect the `h` used in the k1...k4 functions. Consider:`>> h = 1;
>> g = @(x) x+h;
>> g(0)
ans =  1
>> h = 2;
>> g(0)
ans =  1`

Comment: I'm wrong about the indexing and for loop variable scope issue. You still have a problem with changing `h`. The code as it is posted here will not run because `h` is undefined. To see this, use `clear all` instead of clearing only specific variables. The `h` in your `k` functions is whatever value `h` had when you defined those functions. I suggest using N=N*2 for the explicit Euler code to get the results much faster.

Comment: N=i at the end of each for loop so both produced the same results.  I did also change the while loop to use abs() as it's cleaner. Using h in my function was the main problem.  I'm not sure I understand though, why the functions of k1...k4 would not use the new h from each iteration.  I'll try to rewrite the code with k1...k4 not as functions but as scalars changing with each loop.

Comment: with a different `f` you would need to change the `while` logic because the approximate answer could be greater than exact answer. I don't see how avoiding `abs` makes the code "cleaner". With `abs` the same code works with any `f`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f4-70115.html#f4-71621

> Variables specified in the body of the expression [...] must have a value assigned
>   to them at the time you construct an anonymous function that uses them. Upon 
>   construction, MATLAB captures the current value for each variable specified in 
>   the body of that function. The function will continue to associate this value
>   with the variable even if the value should change in the workspace or go out
>   of scope.

The value of `h` in `k1`...`k4` remains constant even though you change `h` in the `while` loop.

One solution is to add `h` to the anonymous functions:

```
k1=@(x,y,h) h*f(x,y);
```

Comment: Thank you! That explains how those functions work.  And adding h as a variable of the function is much easier than rewriting the lops with a scalar h.  I could use one clarification, I ran the code with both `k1=@(x,y,h) h*f(x,y);` and `k1=@(x,y,h) h*f(x(i),y(i));` and both worked.  MATLAB seemed to recognize i as an index instead of a scalar (since I hadn't defined i yet).  Is this a correct interpretation or did I miss a difference in the output?

Comment: @Dominik My guess is that you had `i` being 1 when you defined the anonymous function. If `i` were undefined you would have obtained an error when calling `k1()`. I like to use `clear all` at the top of my scripts to make sure I don't have unexpected variables.